# Como deserializar Json Springboot webservice

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Estou tentando consumir o webservice themoviedb e estou me deparando com seguinte erro.

-----------------------POJO------------------------
    package com.wsemovie.model;

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Movie {

    public String adult;        
    public String budget;            
    public String  original_language;
    public String  original_title;
    public String  overview;    
    public String  title;


    public Movie() {
        super();
    }
    public String getAdult() {
        return adult;
    }
    public void setAdult(String adult) {
        this.adult = adult;
    }
    public String getBudget() {
        return budget;
    }
    public void setBudget(String budget) {
        this.budget = budget;
    }
    public String getOriginal_language() {
        return original_language;
    }
    public void setOriginal_language(String original_language) {
        this.original_language = original_language;
    }
    public String getOriginal_title() {
        return original_title;
    }
    public void setOriginal_title(String original_title) {
        this.original_title = original_title;
    }
    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }
    public void setOverview(String overview) {
        this.overview = overview;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

--------------Controller---------------------

```
@Controller
public class MovieController {   
    @GetMapping("/") 
    @ResponseBody
    public String movies(Model model ) {        
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> resposne = 
                restTemplate.exchange(
                "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/55?api_key=8a39fa19e513b70d41402ac67813ae35",            
                HttpMethod.GET,
                null,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Movie>>() { }
                );
        List<Movie> lista = resposne.getBody();

        model.addAttribute("lista", lista);
        return "movie"; //Invocando o template thymeleaf
    }   
}
```

----------------------JSON-----------------------------------

{
    "adult": false,
    "backdrop_path": "/AuXC0SsPZaAfddtSMnxSnbEeEjR.jpg",
    "belongs_to_collection": null,
    "budget": 2000000,
    "genres": [
        {
            "id": 18,
            "name": "Drama"
        },
        {
            "id": 53,
            "name": "Thriller"
        }
    ],
    "homepage": null,
    "id": 55,
    "imdb_id": "tt0245712",
    "original_language": "es",
    "original_title": "Amores perros",
    "overview": "Three different people in Mexico City are catapulted into dramatic and unforeseen circumstances in the wake of a terrible car crash: a young punk stumbles into the sinister underground world of dog fighting; an injured supermodel's designer pooch disappears into the apartment's floorboards; and an ex-radical turned hit man rescues a gunshot Rotweiler.",
    "popularity": 5.686,
    "poster_path": "/8gEXmIzw1tDnBfOaCFPimkNIkmm.jpg",
    "production_companies": [
        {
            "id": 5084,
            "logo_path": null,
            "name": "Altavista Films",
            "origin_country": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 11230,
            "logo_path": null,
            "name": "Zeta Film",
            "origin_country": ""
        }
    ],
    "production_countries": [
        {
            "iso_3166_1": "MX",
            "name": "Mexico"
        }
    ],
    "release_date": "2000-06-16",
    "revenue": 20908467,
    "runtime": 154,
    "spoken_languages": [
        {
            "iso_639_1": "es",
            "name": "Español"
        }
    ],
    "status": "Released",
    "tagline": "Love. Betrayal. Death.",
    "title": "Amores Perros",
    "video": false,
    "vote_average": 7.7,
    "vote_count": 855
}

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Error while extracting response for type
>   [java.util.List] and content type
>   [application/json;charset=utf-8]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList`
>   out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT
>   token at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while
>   extracting response for type
>   [java.util.List] and content type
>   [application/json;charset=utf-8]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList`
>   out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT
>   token  at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que vi você esta deserializando um `List<Cotacao>` e não um `Movie` como você incluiu na pergunta, provavelmente o retorno JSON não é uma lista e você está tentando deserializar para lista.

**Edit**

Verificando seu JSON você está recebendo apenas **uma** instância do `Movie`, e está fazendo o parse diretamente para `List<Movie>`. Troque deu código para serializar apenas `Movie` ao invés da lista

Comment: @Robson se possível também poste o JSON de retorno do serviço

Comment: Acabei fazendo um mistura pq estava trabalhando em dois projetos (principiante). O Json pode esta no link https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/55?api_key=8a39fa19e513b70d41402ac67813ae35

Comment: De qualquer forma, você esta recebendo apenas um Movie no JSON e deserializando uma lista.

Comment: Altere o código para considerar apenas o Movie, e tente novamente

Comment: Alterei a url para receber um lista de filmes, e retorna o mesmo erro.
"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=8a39fa19e513b70d41402ac67813ae35" É como se api_key nao fosse passado pelo restTemplate.

Comment: Mapiei o Json com http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ para gerar o POJO, gerando todas as classes envolvidas,porem nao obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

Ao que tudo indica, a chamada à API retornaria alguns atributos que comporiam seu objeto Movie, e não uma lista deles. Você poderia tentar a seguinte abordagem:  deserializar o JSON populando um objeto Movie e depois adicionando o objeto à lista com a biblioteca gson do Google:

Dependência:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Implementação:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); //instancie o obj Gson
String jsonInString = resposne.getBody(); //se não for uma String, o que acho difícil, converta
Movie filme = new Movie();
filme = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Movie.class);
lista.add(filme);
```

Pra mais detalhes, dá uma olhada: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/